# Pass arguments to function from BranchPythonOperator in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I am running below code to create DAG. Dags are created but `choose_best_model` Dag is failing. Error is: `ERROR - _choose_best_model() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ti'`. My Airflow version is: **1.10.3**. How Can I resolve this error?

my_dag.py

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

from random import randint
from datetime import datetime

def _choose_best_model(ti):
    accuracies = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=[
        'training_model_A',
        'training_model_B',
        'training_model_C'
    ])
    best_accuracy = max(accuracies)
    if (best_accuracy > 8):
        return 'accurate'
    return 'inaccurate'


def _training_model():
    return randint(1, 10)

with DAG("my_dag", start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval="@daily", catchup=False) as dag:

        training_model_A = PythonOperator(
            task_id="training_model_A",
            python_callable=_training_model
        )

        training_model_B = PythonOperator(
            task_id="training_model_B",
            python_callable=_training_model
        )

        training_model_C = PythonOperator(
            task_id="training_model_C",
            python_callable=_training_model
        )

        choose_best_model = BranchPythonOperator(
            task_id="choose_best_model",
            python_callable=_choose_best_model
        )

        accurate = BashOperator(
            task_id="accurate",
            bash_command="echo 'accurate'"
        )

        inaccurate = BashOperator(
            task_id="inaccurate",
            bash_command="echo 'inaccurate'"
        )

        [training_model_A, training_model_B, training_model_C] >> choose_best_model >> [accurate, inaccurate]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `provide_context` parameter to your operator (it's extending the `PythonOperator` which defines it). You also need to add the `kwargs` to your function's signature.

The full list of parameters in the context which can be passed to your `python_callable` can be found [here (v.1.10.15)](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.15/macros-ref.html).

Once you do this, you can also pass additional custom parameters to your function using the `op_kwargs` parameter.

[`PythonOperator` Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.15/_api/airflow/operators/python_operator/index.html?highlight=branch#airflow.operators.python_operator.PythonOperator)

```
[...]    
def _choose_best_model(ti, **kwargs):   # <-- here 
    accuracies = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=[
        'training_model_A',
        'training_model_B',
        'training_model_C'
    ])
    [...]    
    
with DAG("my_dag", start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval="@daily", catchup=False) as dag:

        [...]    

        choose_best_model = BranchPythonOperator(
            task_id="choose_best_model",
            python_callable=_choose_best_model, 
            provide_context=True,   # <-- here 
        )

        [...]
```